# Title: TypeError: can only join an iterable - Face Recognition Application

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I am developing a Face Recognition application using Python, Tkinter, OpenCV, and MySQL. In my code, I have a function `draw_boundary` which draws rectangles around detected faces and retrieves information from a MySQL database. However, I encountered a `TypeError` with the message "can only join an iterable" specifically on the line where I try to join the variable `n` with `"+".join(n)`.

```
def draw_boundary(img, classifier, scaleFactor, minNeighbors, color, text, clf):
    # ... (Previous code)

    for (x, y, w, h) in features:
        # ... (Previous code)
        my_cursor.execute("select Name from student where StudentId=" + str(id))
        n = my_cursor.fetchone()
        n = "+".join(n)  # The error occurs on this line
```

I am trying to concatenate the values retrieved from the MySQL database using "+".join(), but it seems to be causing a TypeError. I have ensured that the retrieved values are not None before attempting to join them.

I would appreciate assistance in resolving this TypeError and suggestions on how to correctly join the values retrieved from the database in this context.

Comment: I don't know what exactly `n` is, but I'd say there's a high change it is `None`.

Comment: Please use safe escape when putting a variable into a query. Check the example on the following link for how to safely add an id to a query.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeError "can only join an iterable" in your code occurs because the join() method expects an iterable object like a list or tuple, but it's receiving a non-iterable type (which i'm guessing is probably the case here).

You can try to check if the fetched value is a single string or a tuple. (or None but you've already done that).

```
n = my_cursor.fetchone()

# Check if the fetched value is not None and handle different scenarios
if n is not None:
    if isinstance(n, tuple):  # Check if t's a tuple
        n = "+".join(n)  # Join the elements of the tuple
    else:
        n = str(n)  # Convert the single value to a string if not a tuple

# Now you can use the `n` variable as a string
text_to_display = f"{text}: {n}" if n is not None else text
```

Comment: hi Ibrahim thanks for helping, its working now but  Name is showing None

Comment: @RahulKoli If the "Name" field from your database is displaying as None, it may imply that the query didn't find a matching StudentId in the student table. Try adding some error handling to check if the query returned None.

Answer (score 0):

`fetchone` retrieves the next row of a query result set and returns a single sequence, or None if no more rows are available.

How sure are you that the previous query is returning any result at all? Does the StudentId exist?

```
n = ('Joseph')
print('_'.join(n))


n = ('Joseph','Broseph')
print('_'.join(n))

n = None
print('_'.join(n))
```

Output

```
J_o_s_e_p_h
Joseph_Broseph
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-5 in line 6
      4 print('_'.join(n))
      5 n = None
----> 6 print('_'.join(n))

TypeError: can only join an iterable
```